# Painting a line with custom brush

Tags: ios, path, core-graphics, brush

How would you paint a line (or path) with custom brush?

This is the brush I'd like to use:

[image]

Now obviously I've tried doing it with:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Path.png"];
UIColor *fillImg = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, fillImg.CGColor);
```

But doing it like that gives a rather weird and unusable result, as if the background was filled with that image and reveal the parts where I paint (just like in the image below).

[image]

I'd like a line between point A and B stroked with that brush, like in the image below:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have a class derived from UIView, added as a subview from storyboard. This is the content of the class:

```
@implementation lineView {
    CGPoint startPoint;
    CGPoint endPoint;
    BOOL gotStart;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context) ;
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Path.png"];
    UIColor *fillImg = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, fillImg.CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 22.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    if (!gotStart) {
        startPoint = location;
        gotStart = TRUE;
    } else {
        gotStart = FALSE;
        endPoint = location;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code in update is all in `drawRect`?

Comment: Yes, it's all in drawRect. Obviously startPoint and endPoint is outside, in touchesEnded, so line is drawn between two points the user taps to. But you can also assume they're a constants if you'd like, with the line between them at 45 degree.

Comment: You set the line width to 22.0, what is size of the "Path.png".

Comment: Size is 193x22. Added full code of my class. Also Path.png is the first image from this question.

Comment: You can't achieve using custom brush. It will work as you expected only if the two point has the same value on y axis.

Comment: Well that's crap... And even then, based on the y value, the brush will start from different part (ex: shows 20% of the bottom, then 80% of the top). One thing I thought of is to calculate the distance between the two points and the angle, then draw a line with that distance and rotate it. Though it's a little tedious still.

Comment: You are right, I have tested it just now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using GLPaint for what you need - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html